# Parallel bubble sorting on arbitrary graphs

Tags: algorithms, graphs, sorting, routing

Are there bubblesort-esque algorithms for sorting on arbitrary graphs?

I'm working on a problem in which $k$ robots are placed randomly on a graph and have to reach their respective goals as quickly as possible. The robots can only move one step at a time and no two robots can simultaneously occupy the same node, but adjacent robots are allowed to swap places. The analogy to bubble sort when $k = |V|$ and the graph is a line is almost perfect (the one difference is that I care more about the total time it takes in the real world for the robots to move and sort themselves, the *makespan*, rather than the number of comparisons or runtime per se. (It would also be nice to minimize the average time for a robot to get to its goal without later being displaced.)

I can prove an $O(k^2+kn)$ bound for the makespan using a simple algorithm in which the robots greedily follow shortest paths to their goals and where robot $x$ only swaps robot $y$ if $y$ is in $x$'s way and y is already at its own goal. But parallel bubblesorting an array takes only $O(n)$ time, and shearsort only takes $O(n^{1/2}\log n)$ time, so I feel like there should be a simple algorithm that is (provably) linear. I would be very happy with a linear result, even if it was just for gridlike graphs (graphs obtained by deleting nodes from grids, thus creating hallways and side rooms etc.), or for trees.

Comment: How do you get the $O(k^2 + kn)$ bound for your simple algorithm?  Is it tight?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "bubble sorting on arbitrary graphs". What you're doing doesn't look at all like sorting: it's a mostly congestion-free routing problem. I doubt that the analogy with bubblesort on a path is likely to get you very far.